# Firebase analytics Audience edit/delete disabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

When I go to the audience and click on the 3 dots on the far right end of each row in audience, when clicked on edit, the window for editing pops up but not editable. Everything is greyed out.
Thanks in advance for any info regarding this.

[image of my console when edit auience is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfPDQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. After you have created an Audience, you can only edit the Name or the description. You can't edit any of the conditions, so you need to create a new audience if you want set other conditions.

> Edit an audience After you create an audience, you can edit only the
> name and description.

[Audiences - Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you so much for that clarification.